# php 5.6 to 7.1 and go back

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

Can I back version php? now I use version 5.6 My goal to 7.0-7.2.
I install My site local and choose php 7 or 7.2. It works without issue.
if I set ver 7 and find some issue. Can I back ver php to 5.6 or I have to repair backup?
I use Godaddy host. but other has c panel like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always good advice to take a usable back up of your site before making any changes to important aspects like PHP. Having said that I haven't had any issues switching back to previous versions of PHP over the years when needed.

The most likely issues you will encounter moving from PHP 5 to PHP 7.x will be whether all the required PHP extensions are provided by the host company. You may receive an error about something not being found and you will have to go into the setting for PHP in your hosting account and select the correct to include that extension in your environment. Until you resolve the issue you may need to fall back to the previous version of PHP.

A sample of the options set in my environment.
[image: Sample of PHP extension for 7.4]

Comment: This means I can set php7 and if it doesn't work for me, I can switch back? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. Back up your site to be sure and then you should be able to  change to PHP 7.x and change back to PHP 5.x if you have to.

Comment: Thank you, sir. If local, I don't have a problem, I want to believe it will work correctly on hosting too.